# "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Call to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load` has the following error: `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object`. Below is the code snippet for this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext ctx;
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file;
ctx.Load(file, fl => fl.Level, fl => fl.Versions.Include(v => v.CheckInComment, v => v.Created, v => v.CreatedBy, v => v.ID, v => v.IsCurrentVersion, v => v.Size, v => v.Url, v => v.VersionLabel));
```

I'm basically trying to retrieve properties for an uploaded file to a SharePoint personal site's Documents list. This call is successful for the majority of our data in the past except for this specific file. I tried downloading the same file and uploading it and the call above was successful for that new upload. I tried looking into this file's properties, field values, and other information from the corresponding list item and I found nothing out of the ordinary.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit the file from UI directly?

Comment: Edit in what way? It's an uploaded zip file, by the way. Thanks!